# How to develop a new tab page replacement addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to develop a new tab page replacement addon for Firefox, such as New Tab Plus, New Tab King, etc. If you can provide a tutorial, an example walk-through, or what's needed, that'd be great.

There is surprisingly little to none info on this on the Web.

Thanks!

Comment: This addon I made here does this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/homepage-new-tab/

Comment: @Noitidart How did you make Homepage New Tab? Can you give a general outline/steps? What api/sdk/preference did you use to put search box onto new tab page? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I didn't use addon-sdk it's a bootstrap addon you can see the source here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/233405/

Comment: there's an about:config preference alled `newtab.url` something like this you can set it to whatever you want, like a custom page in your addon data folder

Comment: I think this (not very good) question has been answered pretty well by Noitidart, you should upvote him.

Comment: @Noitidart Thank you for your replies! I understand that Homepage New Tab is a bootstrapped addon. What about the other new tab page replacement addons, such as IOS7 New Tab, New Tab Plus, etc.? I didn't see a bootstrap manifest in IOS7 New Tab, so is it developed with SDK? If I want to develop a new tab page replacement addon with SDK, how should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: @canuckistani I asked this question because I didn't find anything related after much searching. What I want to find out is how to develop a new tab page replacement addon for Firefox with SDK. So far I managed to put an icon on the toolbar, click the icon to open a custom new tab page. What I really want is to have a custom new tab page open after clicking the new tab icon, the way IOS7 New Tab, New Tab Plus, New Tab King, etc., do.

Comment: As the other answer suggested, you need to set the newtab global preference. The SDK has an api specifically to allow you to manipulate lowere-level preferences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service

Comment: @Noitidart How do I upvote you? There are no up arrow next to comments.

Comment: Thanks @startupfounder! Your thanks is enough :) I was too lazy to summarize it like Erik so he gets the points please :)

Comment: As of Firefox 41.0, the browser.newtab.url preference has been disabled due to complaints of it being abused. How should this be gone about now? Can this question be re-opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that needs to be done are two things:

1. Make an add-on / website with a page which can be used as the new tab page.
2. change the value of the `browser.newtab.url` preference (and make sure it is restored on unload)

Comment: I'm using your suggestion now. I'll let you know if I can get it to work. In the mean time, can you tell me how I can make Firefox restart after an add-on is installed? The new tab page replacement add-on would only work after a restart. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't need a restart.

Comment: As of Firefox 41.0, the `browser.newtab.url` preference has been disabled due to complaints of it being abused. How should this be gone about now?